# How to increment a numeric string value in angular js

Tags: javascript

I have numeric value as a String and I want to increment its value.
In java we used to do it with Integer.parseInt but I am not getting how to achieve this in angular.

My Controller Code:

```
var count="18"; 
jsonData["combinationsData"]
                                         .push( {
                                            "vAxis": count,
                                         "dataValue":dataValue
                                         } )
                                        count++;//I want to increment its value
```

I want to increment the count value to "19","20" so on, Please suggest how could I increment a String represented numeric value.

Comment: In JS you can just use `parseInt` function on the string.

Comment: why are you using a string for a count in the first place?  is this set somewhere else that doesn't allow for numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
count = "78";

count = ((+count)+1).toString();

console.log(count);
```

`+count` converts it to a number; `+1` increments it; `.toString()` converts to it back to a string.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var count="18";  
jsonData["combinationsData"]
                                             .push( {
                                                "vAxis": count,
                                             "dataValue":dataValue
                                             } );
                                            count = (parseInt(count)+1).toString();
```

or:

```
var count=18;  
jsonData["combinationsData"]
                                             .push( {
                                                "vAxis": count.toString(),
                                             "dataValue":dataValue
                                             } );
                                            count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt to get an int value out of your string value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
var myInt = parseInt(count);
myInt++;
```